# How To Get A Quaternion Camera Rotation That Is Independent Of View Orientation

Tags: camera, quaternion

Here is the problem,

If I roll the view 90 degrees using <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>6</kbd>. All of the view controls stop working correctly.

Rotating with the mouse left and right causes camera rotation up and down and vice versa.

Its impossible to use.

All other 3D modeling programs resolved this issue using quaternions for camera controls, so that camera controls work the same way independently of the where the camera is and what angle it is rotated to.

Is it possible to get this kind of control with Blender? Or is it not going to work with the view rotated 90 degrees perpendicular to the screen.

Answer (score 0):

I've never experienced myself the specific problem that you are talking about, so I don't actually know if this fixes it, but you are able to change the rotation mode for the camera from XYZ to Quaternion.

The image below shows the setting being changed in the properties panel.

[image: changing rotation mode]

I hope this helps! (but it might not, idk)